# Secure way to POST to Django from a trusted external (Node-RED) server?

Tags: django, authentication, post, csrf, node-red

### What I want

I have a Node-RED instance on one server doing real-time analysis of a data stream.  I want it to securely notify a Django app on a different server of any actionable findings.

[Edit: I bundle findings to rate-limit requests to 1/second, but any solution needs to be performant enough to not slow it further than that.]

### Problem

By default Django protects against cross-site request forgeries by requiring "unsafe" requests (like POST) to contain a CSRF token/secret that Django provides (as a cookie? rendered into the page?) when rendering an HTML form containing the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag or a view decorated with `csrf_protect`.

The above seems like it will only allow POSTS starting from pages that the Django app itself served (that's probably the point).  My Node-RED instance is not requesting a page from Django to start with, so it has no token/secret to include in a POST.

### Approaches considered so far:

#### Use GET requests instead

The requests Node-RED would be sending *will* cause side-effects in Django, and I don't want a third party sending bogus requests and making Django do somersaults for no reason.

#### Remove check using Django's `csrf_exempt` decorator

See above.

[Edit 2: Think I'll actually go with this option, since 1) both the Node-RED and Django servers are on an internal network that's inaccessible from the outside web and 2) looking more closely, it seems that the actions my requests are supposed to trigger are already accessible in views that are `csrf_exempt`.]

#### Use HTTP basic authentication

The Node-RED `http request` node has an option to set a username/password to be sent in (I think) the `WWW-Authenticate` header and I found [this decorator](https://github.com/m7v8/django-basic-authentication-decorator) to map basic auth to django auth.

By default, though, basic auth is sent in plaintext, which is *bad*.  The `http request` node does also have an option to enable SSL/TLS and specify certs, private keys, etc., but unfortunately the Django site does not use HTTPS (I hate this, but it's not a priority for my employers atm).

#### Trust POSTs from [Node-RED hostname]

I'm not sure what the best way is to do this.  To my knowledge, there is no guaranteed way to determine client hostname from a request.  You can get IP, but my Node-RED server uses DHCP so its IP isn't static.  Something like this *might* work:

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse
from socket import gethostbyaddr

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    # retrieve the client IP from the request
    # use gethostbyaddr to do a DNS lookup on the IP and get a hostname
    # if hostname matches [Node-RED hostname]:
        # process the body of the request
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    # else:
        return HttpResponse(status=403)
```

I feel like this isn't airtight; my understanding of networking is weak, but if the Node-RED server loses its DHCP lease because it's rebooting or the network is under heavy load or something, an attacker could get a lease for that hostname and send malicious requests.

If the client hostname is unreliable and the client IP is dynamic, putting some kind of custom secret in the request headers could be useful, but only if it's encrypted - otherwise it's trivial to copy.  I don't know what decent approach to doing that would be.

Are any of these approaches close to a good solution?  Is there something built in somewhere for this situation?

Comment: How does the Node-RED instance authenticate to Django?

Comment: Why not just encrypt the POSTed data?

Comment: On a side note: with services like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), there's really no excuse to _not_ use HTTPS. It's free, easy to set up, and can even be completely automated.

Comment: @knbk: For now, Node-RED doesn't authenticate to Django in any way; it's just interacting with URLs that Django exposes.  I've set up Let's Encrypt on my own stuff before and love it, but I'm a fairly junior dev here and don't have the clout to push that through. At least this is all internal-only and behind a corporate firewall/proxy.

Comment: @rafalmp: I've never done ad-hoc data encrypt/decrypt before and would have to look up what node/python libraries to use.  This is about the same effort as encrypting a pre-shared secret, as I mentioned in the next to last paragraph.
I assume any notable service that issues API keys (github, steam, etc) is using HTTPS to protect against sniffing the key en route?

Comment: If no authentication is used, CSRF is not an issue, so you probably should use `@csrf_exempt`. I wouldn't recommend ad-hoc encryption, encryption is difficult to get right (even when using crypto libraries) and setting up HTTPS is much easier and less error-prone than setting up any ad-hoc encryption. Hostnames are easily spoofed, so that's of no use either. Is the Node RED instance on your internal network? Is Django reachable from outside the network?

Comment: @knbk both servers are on the internal network and unreachable from the outside, so I suppose the threat model is "someone with employee login info decides to make bogus POSTs", at which point everything is shot anyway.  I just looked through the Django codebase and most of the actions that these requests would trigger are already accessible through pre-existing `@csrf_exempt` views anyway, so I guess I'll go that way.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

To use django API, you may consider using [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) as it will allow you to perfom HTTP requests without any CSRF token.

For example, create an endpoint with the [Views Tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#views) and use the [`AllowAny` Permission](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#allowany):

`views.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'username', 'email', 'groups']

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny] # or permissions.IsAuthenticated
```

`urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from tutorial.quickstart import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Then run `manage.py runserver` and perform a GET or POST request:

- POST /users/ {"username": "test"} -> `201 Created`
- GET /users/ -> `200 OK`